# MySQL table Partition with FLOOR function (partition function not allowed)?

Tags: mysql, function, range, database-partitioning, floor

I'm trying to make a partitioned table with the following RANGE function

```
CREATE TABLE `fact_events` (
`event_key` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_type_key` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`analytic_file_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL ',
`sdk_session_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`virtual_button_create_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL C,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_key`),
 KEY `idx_events_event_type` (`event_type_key`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
  PARTITION BY RANGE(FLOOR(event_key/100000))
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0),
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
 PARTITION p513 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
 )
```

I keep getting

```
ERROR 1564 (HY000): This partition function is not allowed
```

Any ideas would be welcome
thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL documents the partitioning functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html).  The `floor()` function appears to have some special considerations.  In this case, I think the issue might be that the division is returning a float/double result rather than a decimal result.

This is easily fixed in your case because you do not need to do the division:

```
CREATE TABLE `fact_events` (
    `event_key` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_type_key` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `analytic_file_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `sdk_session_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `virtual_button_create_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`event_key`),
     KEY `idx_events_event_type` (`event_type_key`)
 ) PARTITION BY RANGE(event_key) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0),
     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (100000),
     PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (200000),
     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (300000),
     PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (40000000),
     PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
 )
```

EDIT:

As an explanation.  `floor()` returns an integer *value* but not necessarily an integer *type*.  Here is the documentation:

> For exact-value numeric arguments, the return value has an exact-value
>   numeric type. For string or floating-point arguments, the return value
>   has a floating-point type.

When you divide two integers, you produce a floating point argument and this is not appropriate for partitioning.

Comment: thanks, I'll implement it that way, but how do you explain the issue with `floor`? doesn't `floor` return an integer by definition?